# is it safe to remove a generic type constraint?

Tags: c#, generics, backwards-compatibility

```
interface IFoo<in T> where T : Bar {
    Do(T bar);
}
```

Is it possible to break anything by removing the constraint on `T`?

I don't think you can break any implementation of `IFoo` because they either implement it with a concrete type `MyFoo : IFoo<MyBar>`, or they declare the same / a stronger constraint when the implementation is generic itself `MyFoo<T> : IFoo<T> where T : MyBar`.

I also don't think you can break any usages of the interface, because again such a method either passes a concrete type `foo.Do(new MyBar)` or it declares the same / a stronger constraint `UseFoo<T>(...) where T : MyBar`.

Am I missing any situation where even a *binary* backwards incompatibility could arise?

Comment: `MyBar` will have to inherit from `Bar`. If `Bar` define e.g. `SomeMethod()`, then removing it from definition will stop compiling at e.g. `bar.SomeMethod();` line. So yes (actully, no, not safe), not only you let anything be to used as `bar`, you also *may* break existing code.

Comment: Adding and removing generic constraints is allways a breaking change as you´re adding/removing methods from the API that are used within your generic type. In your case you can´t call any member of `Bar` anymore as `Bar` is completely unknown.

Comment: @Sinatr with `class Bar { public void SomeMethod() { } }`  `class MyBar : Bar { }`  `class Foo : IFoo<MyBar> { public void Do(MyBar bar) { bar.SomeMethod(); } }` I can remove the type constraint without compile errors. Can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: @HimBromBeere I can't reproduce your issue (see my previous comment). Can you clarify?

Comment: @PatrickHuizinga yes but in your example you directly use dependency to `MyBar` in `Do` method

Comment: type constraint will not let you implement your interface with following definition `class NotBar { }` `class SomeClass : IFoo<NotBar> { }`

Comment: @hmnzr I'll give you 1 guess why I want to remove the constraint ;)

Comment: @PatrickHuizinga, you are right (and I was wrong), since you specify `MyBar` as `T` which inherit from `Bar` there is no need for constraint `where T: Bar` to be able to call `SomeMethod()`. The second statement still apply, you can now create a `class AnotherBar: IFoo<string>`, though I am not able to produce a *broken* due to this change case.